# Stand of Yemen in the Soviet-Afghan War of 1979?

Tags: soviet-union, afghanistan

Just wanted to know the role of Democratic Yemen in the Soviet-Afghan war. Like: "What did it do? Who were its allies and enemies?"

Yemen was actually really disturbed by the Yemenite war. The Yemenite war was between North and the South Yemen. The war developed out of a breakdown in relations between the two countries after the presidents of both were overthrown in coups. I think it was an ally of USA though their relation were not strong. But I can't find what Yemen actually did in Afghanistan.

Comment: What information do you already know? What have you searched for?

Comment: 3rd question about "the impact of XXX on the afghan war" in as many days. What's going on here?

Comment: If it is urgent, perhaps you could edit the question with clarifications in response to the comments (do not reply in comments; edit the question).    The first comment should be clarified; what have you searched and what have you found. There is no point in our repeating research you've already done.

Comment: Also worth nothing that questions phrased as questions tend to get more answers than noun phrases that require the reader to figure out what you're looking for.

Comment: There was no "Yemen" during the time of the other war. There were two countries on that territory claiming to be 'democratic' in nature and it is unclear to which you are referring; both? Note that this not intended as an actual answer, but to your headline it would be: "Divided!"

Comment: I was assigned democratic Yemen...don't know which one was it?

Comment: THat would be a good candidate for [research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Yemen)

Answer (score 1):

> As a direct result of the so-called ‘Brezhnev doctrine’, the USSR asserted its “right and duty” to go to war in foreign countries “if and when an existing socialist regime was threatened.”[5] This accounts for the increased overseas military, political, and economic support being given at this time to pro-Marxist régimes in Nicaragua, Angola, Ethiopia, Mozambique, Yemen, etc. *[e-ir-info](https://www.e-ir.info/2010/01/03/the-soviet-union%E2%80%99s-last-war/)*

If Yemen was a Marxist regime, then presumably it supported Soviet action - because the way to spot the freedom arising from Socialism & Communism is to recognize the slavish adherence to ideology.  Freedom, after all, is slavery, and the class interest of the proletariat classes is best recognized in their inability to express any opinions differing from their overlords.

If I were researching for a model UN presentation, I'd make sure that the Yemen in question was  aligned with the Soviet axis of the Marxist Church, and that their ideology wasn't contaminated by any schismatic forces.

> The PDRY, with support from the Soviet Union, Cuba, and East Germany, responded by invading the north using 3 regular divisions and a Tactical Air Force regiment. *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yemenite_War_of_1979)*

If the PDRY was deploying troops Soviet support, then it is likely that the PDRY adhered closely to whatever claptrap was emerging from Soviet apparatchik at the time.  If the Soviets stated that their invasion of Afghanistan was necessary to  defend communism from the extensive Afghani Capitalist Bourgeoisie, then the Yemeni would nod and smile and produce twenty-seven eight-by-ten color glossy photographs with circles and arrows and a paragraph on the back of each one illustrating the evils of the Capitalist pig dogs controlling the Afghani civilization.  Truth, after all, is a lie; only Soviets tell truth; everything else in the world is merely the ramblings of counter-revolutionary propaganda specialists.

One other note - I don't recall the Yemeni order of battle, but I doubt that the Yemeni did anything in Afghanistan.  I don't think Yemen had the ability to deploy forces overseas, and unless they trained with the Soviets, they'd be more of a hindrance than a help.  Yemen's stance was probably just to (verbally) support the Soviet defense of the Afghan Socialist Republic [Sic].  A quick google search supports my hypothesis that Yemeni troops don't deploy outside of Yemen.

Comment: +1 for the Alice's restaurant reference!  Also the answer isn't half bad either!

Comment: There are a lot of suppositions in this answer and little in the way of facts. It reads more as a passionate rant about the Soviet Union.

Comment: I won't argue, but I'd offer two caveats - (1) the rant is about communism, not the Soviet Union, and (2) I offered more research than the original question, and the cited research *answers the question*.  Check the comments on the question - OP was non-responsive to multiple requests for clarification. I created the answer mostly as a way to estimate how much effort was really involved.